# Get data on the basis of user selection

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to develop an application in which there are branch(computer science, mechanical,civil...etc) and there respective semesters. I want a option menu on first start of the application that asks for a particular branch and semester and on the basis of the selection download the questions of different subject of that semester and branch.

I tried this code that checks weather the app is first started :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Perhaps set content view here

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.myAppName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
            // Do first run stuff here then set 'firstrun' as false
            // using the following line to edit/commit prefs
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Now how can i download the data based on used selection?

Answer (score 0):

You must be displaying all the details in a list view, If so then whenever user clicks any list item you can get Branch Id and semester Id together and query database for questions.

Comment: What i want is when the application starts, it asks the user for its branch and semester, on the basis of that all the data from cloud is downloaded to the app and will be displayed in listview...JSON will do that but how?

Comment: You want to know how to make request? or I am wrong?

Comment: This is my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pKLabs.RgpvDigest, it is currently for Computer science i want for other branches, i dont know how to write JSON i have gone through this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ so how to get started?

Comment: You have got a good example, download their code and try to run it. Its explanation is very simple to start with.

Answer (score 0):

you need to go through following steps.

1> when your application starts, get your semester and branch values from user in any control like spinner or edittext or some other control and store them in object.

2> now prepare the query with your values.

```
eg. "select * from yourtablename where yourcolumnname='yourvaluestored'"
```

3> download the data based on this query from your cloud.